# Create new columns based on existing category rows

Tags: sql

just need to minimize rows and create new columns based on the type ... data set like

What would I use for this?

Existing Data

| Day | Region | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1 | USA | States | 50 |
| 1/1 | USA | Cities | 25 |
| 1/1 | USA | Regions | 10 |
| 2/1 | CA | States | 49 |
| 2/1 | CA | Cities | 40 |
| 2/1 | CA | Regions | 35 |

Update to

| Day | Region | States | Cities | Regions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1 | USA | 50 | 25 | 10 |
| 2/1 | CA | 49 | 40 | 35 |

I was using case when but that gave me blanks which isn't what I needed

case when type = States then amount end as states

Comment: I'd consider creating a view.

Comment: can you share the query?

Comment: The existing database is poorly designed take a look here [db design and normalization](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=modeling-normalization-in-database-design). Normalization helps you avoid redundancies and inconsistencies in your database.

Comment: Google for "SQL pivot query."

Comment: What RDBMS do you use? Generally, what you need here is named "conditional aggregation". Will help to search for that.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the conditional aggregation :

```
select Day, Region, sum(case when Type = 'States' then Amount else 0 end) as States,
                    sum(case when Type = 'Cities' then Amount else 0 end) as Cities,
                    sum(case when Type = 'Regions' then Amount else 0 end) as Regions
from mytable
group by Day, Region
```